# Access Audit Trail

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was searching this site and came up with a post about adding an audit trail.  The post suggests two ways for doing this and I like the second one as does the user who wrote the post.  I am curious as to where do I add this code?  Does it go into the text field after update event or somewhere else.  The original post can be located here:
[VBA: OpenRecordset .AddNew method runs slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606946/vba-openrecordset-addnew-method-runs-slow/31746215#31746215)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I have used this guide in the past for creating audit trails:

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut21.htm

Comment: Hi Mark,  I reviewed that code awhile back and it seems to only work with bounded fields.  All my fields are unbounded.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Form event AfterUpdate to track changes for all fields on the form. AfterUpdate for field can be undone.