# Recordset Update error when I'm not trying to update

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

This code looks at an open form and copies the contents of some controls into the current record of a recordset.

```
MyRecordset.FindFirst "[Asset ID] =  " & Forms![Asset Details]![ID].Value

For Each ctl In Forms![Asset Details].Controls
    s = "N/A"
    On Error Resume Next
        s = ctl.ControlSource
    On Error GoTo 0
    If s <> "N/A" Then
            'Fill in field
            MyRecordset.Fields(s).Value = ctl.Value  'Error 3020: Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit          
    End If
Next ctl
```

Why am I getting Error 3020, when I'm not using `.Update` or `.CancelUpdate`?

Comment: Because code is updating a record in recordset object. Must first set for EditMode, populate field, then Update. Are form and recordset using different table sources? Why do you need to copy data?

Comment: _Why am I getting Error 3020, when I'm not using .Update or .CancelUpdate?_ Because you stopped reading the mesage. Continue: "... without AddNew or Edit".

Comment: @June7 The recordset is a change log. It's a table of the changed fields in the form, which is connected to a different table.

Comment: Why would you think didn't need to use? Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-edit-method-dao. If this is a change log, are you actually creating a new record instead of editing an existing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-addnew-method-dao

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606946/vba-openrecordset-addnew-method-runs-slow/31746215#31746215 and http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html

Comment: @Gustav and @June7  Basically, I misunderstood what  `.Edit` was for, and the MS developer pages that I read didn't explain it very well, which is why I generally don't bother with them. But I added `.Edit` and it works now. Thanks to you both.